# connect-redis doesn't want to connect to remote host

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Preamble: I'm running a node app on AWS EB and I'm using Elasticache redis server for session management. I'm trying to connect to elasticache using connect-redis and it doesn't seem to be using the host setting that I provide, instead defaulting to 127.0.0.1.

I'm running a node app with a redis server set up for cache. main.js below:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var redis   = require("redis");
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(expressSession);

// Application libraries
var express = require('express');

// Redis client
var redisclient  = redis.createClient();
redisclient.on("error", function (err)
{
    console.log("REDIS Error " + err);
});

// Initialise the application
var app = express();

var sessionport = isNaN(process.env.SESSION_PORT) ? 6379 : Number(process.env.SESSION_PORT);
console.log('redis://' + process.env.SESSION_HOST + ':' + sessionport);
var store = new redisStore({
    host: process.env.SESSION_HOST,
    port: sessionport,
    client: redisclient,
    ttl :  2.29e+7
});
app.use(expressSession({
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: store
}));
```

My environment variables are:

```
SESSION_HOST: my-session-host.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com
SESSION_PORT: 6379
SESSION_SECRET: supersecret
```

However, when my server starts up I'm seeing the following output from the node output:

```
Worker #1 is online. (pid 17643)
redis://liamegan-session-001.i0o002.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
REDIS Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
REDIS Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
REDIS Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

It looks like it's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 despite my providing it with a host. I've also tried constructing and providing a redis URL to the redisStore constructor.

Any I doing something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was that I was supplying the existing redisclient to the redisStore constructor. Doing this trumps the creation of a new client and therefore overrides the host and port set there. To fix this, I simply added the host and port to redis.createClient.

```
// Redis client
var sessionport = isNaN(process.env.SESSION_PORT) ? 6379 : Number(process.env.SESSION_PORT);
var redisclient  = redis.createClient({
    host: process.env.SESSION_HOST,
    port: sessionport
});
```